# Notification about restricted access to photos is not localized

Tags: ios

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsvuQ.jpg)I'm using the PHPhotoLibrary.reauestAuthorization method and the first time I install the application, I get a notification about granting access to photos. The notification is fully localized.
However, if you select limited access to photos, then the notification of partial access will not be localized. Always stays in English. What could be the problem if the first notification is localized and the second is not

I added the Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description key to the project
I also changed the system language on the device. The text is completely changed to another language in the first notification about choosing access to Photos. But the partial permission notice for the photo always remains in English

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.